# Is there a way to underlay one image for a menu and the fragment under it?

Tags: java, android

I am using an image for the background and would like the image to underlay the entire screen, including the menu above it. Is there a way to do that besides chopping the image up in some complicated fashion?

Answer (score 0):

Using vh should work. It will set the image to be the total height of the user's viewport.

```
img {
   height: 100vh;
}
```

Or setting this on the body.

```
body {
   background-image: url(yourImage.jpg);
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was overthinking it. Setting the background in the base activity (so that it's over the Viewpager) and then removing the background in the fragments did the trick.